# MVC4 Knockout data-bind click event not firing

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I am getting started with Knockout and having an issue with click event not firing.

The above is not firing the GetWaiters function. Not sure what I am doing wrong or missing.

TIA

I have the following html:

```
<h2>Create</h2>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>WaiterId</th>
            <th>RestId</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: Waiters">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: waiter_id"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: rest_id"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<br />
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/myBundle")   
<input type="button" id="btnGetWaiters" value="Get Waiters" data-bind="click: GetWaiters" />

And following in my js file:

var WaiterViewModel = function () {
    //Make the self as 'this' reference
    var self = this;
    //Declare observable which will be bind with UI 
    self.waiter_id = ko.observable("0");
    self.rest_id = ko.observable("0");
    self.name = ko.observable("");

    //The Object which stored data entered in the observables
    var WaiterData = {
        waiter_id: self.waiter_id,
        rest_id: self.rest_id,
        name: self.name
    };

    //Declare an ObservableArray for Storing the JSON Response
    self.Waiters = ko.observableArray([]);

    GetWaiters(); //Call the Function which gets all records using ajax call

    //Function to Read All Employees
    function GetWaiters() {
        alert("fetching");
        //Ajax Call Get All Employee Records
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/api/WaiterAPI",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                self.Waiters(data); //Put the response in ObservableArray
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert(error.status + "<--and--> " + error.statusText);
            }
        });
        //Ends Here
    }
};
ko.applyBindings(new WaiterViewModel());
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you trying to bind click event the binding method should be the method of the view model but in your implementation `GetWaiters()` is declared as private method. Define this method like this and try again:

```
self.GetWaiters =  function() {
    // your code
};
```

Comment: Made the changes and tried calling it: self.GetWaiters(). I am getting the following error: TypeError: self.GetWaiters is not a function

Comment: Sorry my bad. Moved the call self.GetWaiters() below the function and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

your function is fine but the way you declared it is not right.

First try to inspect your model `console.log(new WaiterViewModel())`. you 'll find that it does not have any function with name `GetWaiters()`.  Recalling from @vadim answer `GetWaiters() is declared as private method`.

all what you need to do is to associate `GetWaiters()` with your viewmodel. for example like what you did with `waiter_id`, so declare it like this:

```
self.GetWaiters =  function() { //your code goes here }
```

to call it use this `self.GetWaiters()`

Answer (score 0):

**Small tip**

I had a similar problem with event click binding not firing. The problem was **misspelled** function name in my case. The problem is that knockout is very silent in this case as oposed to bindings that are executed right away, where you get proper errors in console.